# translate postgres sql to linq. Is it possible?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, postgresql

I need translate next sql to linq is it possible? That will have approximately the same speed

```
  SELECT Count(tblcollectionimage.lngimageid), 
   tblcollectiontree.lngcollectionid, 
   tblcollection.txtname 
  FROM   (tblcollectiontree  
          LEFT JOIN tblcollectionimage 
                 ON blcollectiontree.lngcollectionid = 
   tblcollectionimage.lngcollectionid) 
   JOIN tblcollection 
     ON tblcollectiontree.lngcollectionid = tblcollection.lngcollectionid 
  WHERE  lngcollectionparentid = 0 
  GROUP  BY tblcollectiontree.lngcollectionid, 
      tblcollection.txtname
```

I have currently such linq but it doesn't work.

```
  var results =(from collection in dataBase.tblcollections 
  join collectionTree in dataBase.tblcollectiontrees on 
  collection.lngcollectionid equals collectionTree.lngcollectionid 
  into generalCollections
  from generalCollection in generalCollections 
  join images in dataBase.tblcollectionimages on 
  collection.lngcollectionid equals images.lngcollectionid 
  into generalCollectionImages
  from generalCollectionImage in 
  generalCollectionImages.DefaultIfEmpty()
  group generalCollectionImage by 
  generalCollectionImage.lngcollectionid into hello
  from hellos in hello.DefaultIfEmpty() 
  join collection in dataBase.tblcollections on 
  hello.Key equals collection.lngcollectionid

  select new
  {
      id = hello.Key,
      name = hello.Count()
  }).ToList();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you haven`t already, please take a look at these for tips to improve your questions, and receive better answers: http://stackoverflow.com/tour and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask . Also, please format your code to make it as readable as possible.

Comment: You'll probably want to look into Entity Framework, from what I've gathered. I don't work with .NET myself.